# Error converting data type nvarchar to float when checking greater or less than a number

Tags: sql, sql-server

Please i have a simple query like below.

```
 SELECT d.id,d.dia FROM dbo.debtor d WHERE ISNUMERIC(dia + 'e0') = 1
```

when i run the above does what i want . it returns all the records from the two columns where dia is numeric. However, i want to filter more by adding where dia is numeric and greater or less than a number. My query below fails.

```
  SELECT d.id,d.dia FROM dbo.debtor d 
        WHERE ISNUMERIC(dia + 'e0') = 1  and cast(dia as float)  > 6
```

Please any help would be appreciated. How do i cast the dia which is of nvarchar as float ?

Comment: You should use CASE statement, like "case when isnumeric(...) then ... else 0 end > 6" or something. Conditions in WHERE clause will be evaluated in order, choosen by query optimizer - even using many layers of queries you can't be sure that isnumeric() is evaluated before comparison.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider your WHERE clause

```
WHERE ISNUMERIC(dia + 'e0') = 1  and cast(dia as float)  > 6
```

There is no specific order in which the two conditions will be executed first.
Suppose dia is not numeric and then condition `cast(dia as float)  > 6` gets executed first, then casting in condition `cast(dia as float)` will throw error as value fails being converted to float.

To ensure that casting condition works on numeric value only you will have to apply CASE in WHERE clause as shown below

```
SELECT d.id,d.dia FROM dbo.debtor d 
WHERE ISNUMERIC(dia + 'e0') = 1  and 
      6 < CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(dia + 'e0') = 1 THEN cast(dia as float)  ELSE 1 END
```

Comment: It works and i really love logic. Is there any way we can do this without the CASE. I mean return the value where is greater than 6 only.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
ISNUMERIC('' + dia + 'e0')
```

Comment: Ok The error is at cast(dia as float) or where do i add the ISNUMERIC('' + dia + 'e0') ?

Comment: I'm sorry, i mis-read. dia is of type nvarchar. How about select (cast dia as float) from table, do you get errors?

Comment: I got error because not all values in the dia table are number

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the query plan to see if the where clauses are being evaluated in the correct order.

You can achieve the desired result by placing the second condition in an outer select statement so it only evaluates the records that have a numeric dia.